# How to read XML appSettings from external file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There are a lot of similar questions and I have looked at every one I could find, to no avail.

I'm storing API keys for Google+ authentication in a .config file outside of my solution (in the same level as the solution folder).

I'm attempting to read the values back in Startup.Auth.cs, like so:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GoogleClientId"),
        ClientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GoogleClientSecret")
    });
}
```

Root Web.config:

```
<appSettings file="..\Secrets.config"> <!-- Path is correct, relative to Web.config -->
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Secrets.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="GoogleClientId" value="shh" />
    <add key="GoogleClientSecret" value="shh" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in a .config file outside of my solution (in the same level as the solution folder).

An IIS application is totally unaware of any folders outside of its virtual application folder. There is no "at the same level as a solution file" in the context of a web application because the solution file is not deployed with it.

If you want to put appSettings outside of your application folder, your only built-in choices are the root `web.config` file, or `machine.config` file, which are both global to the machine (but specific to the .NET framework version you are running on). See [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx#scope_of_configuration_settings).

> But just for the record, it is easiest to manage in the long run if you keep application settings in your application's web.config file. Eventually, you will need to change to/add a new web server and you might be scratching your head for a while trying to work out why the settings no longer work when that time comes if they need to be placed outside of your virtual application folder.

Comment: I'm following the suggestions from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure#pwd) guide.

Comment: Yup, works fine with it at the same level. I don't want to keep sensitive information publicly available in my repository, that's why I was attempting to do as Rick Anderson had suggested and put it outside of the solution entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<configuration>...</configuration>` tag from `Secrets.config`

Secrets.config:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="GoogleClientId" value="shh" />
  <add key="GoogleClientSecret" value="shh" />
</appSettings>
```

Basically you make the `appSettings`section the root of the external `Secrets.config` file.

The same can be done for connection strings using the `configSource` attribute except that...

> Security - Unlike the `Secrets.config` file, the external connection
>   strings file must be in the same directory as the root web.config
>   file, so you'll have to take precautions to ensure you don't check it
>   into your source repository.

Also try using the `ConfigurationManager`

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientId"],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientSecret"]
});
```

Referencing articles where I learned about it

Scott Hanselman

[Best practices for private config data and connection strings in configuration in ASP.NET and Azure](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestPracticesForPrivateConfigDataAndConnectionStringsInConfigurationInASPNETAndAzure.aspx)

Official MS documentation

[Best practices for deploying passwords and other sensitive data to ASP.NET and Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure)

Comment: That doesn't do it.

Comment: Just for trouble shooting. does it work when they are on the same level. Just want to rule out that it can work. I have the same in production but in my case the files are on the same root.

Comment: Yeah, it does work if they're on the same level. Just find it odd that the tutorial would be wrong.

Comment: Remember that it does not work if it cannot find the file. Try small steps. Go up one folder and try again an so on. Confirming the file path as you go.

Comment: Well yeah, there is only one step to go up to, and that's what it was initially.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to verify that the secrets.config is copied after the build?

Verify that by right clicking on the file and viewing the properties that the build action of the file is set to copy always.